# If statements for prices

Tags: python, if-statement

I have written a code where the person inputs the amount of money the have and what computer they want, how would I write a code to tell them if the have can afford it or not. (I am only 11 years old so I do not want it to be over complicated)

```
Homebasic_price = 900
Office_price = 1200
Gamer_price = 1500
Studio_price = 2200

price = int(input("How much is the computer you would like?"))

money = int(input("How much money do you have to spend?"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
basic=100
office=200
game=300
studio=400
price=100
if price < basic:
    print("you cant have any PC")
elif price >= basic & price < office:
    print("you can have basic machine")
elif print >= office & price < game:
    print("You can have office PC")

you can have basic machine
```

This is as an example and you can extend your if-else to some other models. Read this for better idea : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: You have to remove price assignment and assign int(input)) to it. So when ever user enters input price will have it.

Comment: If you wanna give more clarity to end user, you need this. Else you can skip.

Comment: Yes. See price is still getting value from normal assignment.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I wasn't reading it properly But I found out what I was doing wrong. Thank you very much this helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

@Ten-Coin already answered your specific question, but since it sounds like you're brand-new to programming, I wanted to offer some more general advice and encouragement.

When you're first starting out with a language--and with programming in general--it's often helpful to follow some tutorials that give you an idea of how the language works. There are [lots](https://www.techrocket.com/coding) [of](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python) [resources](https://www.tynker.com/javascript/) to help you learn Python online that will gradually show you how to build simple at first, then more complicated, projects.

Programming is a lot of fun, so I hope you keep exploring and learning! Good luck!